# How can I take the output of a shell script and place it in a file on the command line?

Tags: unix, shell-script

How can I take the output of a shell script and place it in a file on the command line?

Answer (score 12):

```
# write to file
sh myscript > out.txt
# append to file
sh myscript >> out.txt
# write both output and stderr to file
sh myscript 2&1>> out.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ ./foo >> myoutputfile.txt
```