# Handling whitespaces in the name of a ZFS dataset in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, zfs

I'd like to take output from two commands –

```
zpool list
zfs list
```

and for each found pool:

```
zpool get all nameofpool
```

and for each found file system:

```
zfs get all nameoffilesystem
```

### Background and environment

I'm making local changes to script that's integral to OS X,

`/usr/bin/sysdiagnose`

- `#!/bin/sh` for starters
- always run with superuser privileges
- sometimes effectively headless ([triggered by a key chord](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sysdiagnose.1.html)), so the output must be a file.

#### First experiment

Based on the example at [#65 Remove all ZFS snapshots](http://zackreed.me/articles/65-remove-all-zfs-snapshots):

```
#!/bin/sh
for dataset in `zfs list -H | cut -f 1`
do
  zfs get all $dataset
done
```

That works, but **not** where there's a space in the name of the dataset. For example where the file system is `zhandy/Pocket Time Machine` the output includes:

```
cannot open 'zhandy/Pocket': dataset does not exist
cannot open 'Time': dataset does not exist
cannot open 'Machine': dataset does not exist
```

#### Second experiment

… was based on the first answer to this question – using `IFS` – and made the script more like Apple's. See [revision 4](https://superuser.com/revisions/528942/4).

#### Third experiment

Based on the accepted answer to this question – with `IFS`, and quotation marks for `"$dataset"`:

```
#!/bin/sh
data_directory_path=~/Desktop
ECHO=/bin/echo
ZFS=/usr/sbin/zfs
ZPOOL=/usr/sbin/zpool
# If there exists a zfs binary, get some ZFS information
if [ -f "${ZFS}" ]
then
    "${ECHO}" "Recording ZFS pool version information ..."
    "${ZPOOL}" upgrade &> ${data_directory_path}/zpool\ upgrade.txt
    "${ECHO}" "    listing all ZFS pools ..."
    "${ZPOOL}" list &> ${data_directory_path}/zpool\ list.txt
    "${ECHO}" "    detailed health status and verbose data error information ..."
    "${ZPOOL}" status -v &> ${data_directory_path}/zpool\ status.txt
    "${ECHO}" "    pools that are available but not currently imported"
    "${ZPOOL}" import &> ${data_directory_path}/zpool\ import.txt
    "${ECHO}" "Recording ZFS file system version information ..."
    "${ZFS}" upgrade &> ${data_directory_path}/zfs\ upgrade.txt
    "${ECHO}" "    listing all ZFS file systems ..."
    "${ZFS}" list &> ${data_directory_path}/zfs\ list.txt
    "${ECHO}" "    all properties of each file system"
    OLD_IFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    for dataset in `zfs list -H | cut -f 1`
    do
        "${ZFS}" get all "$dataset" &> ${data_directory_path}/ZFS\ file\ system\ properties.txt
    done
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
    "${ECHO}" "Listing the contents of /dev/dsk"
    "${LS}" -@adel /Volumes &> ${data_directory_path}/ls-dev-dsk.txt
    "${ECHO}" "Listing the contents of /var/zfs/dsk"
    "${LS}" -@adel /Volumes &> ${data_directory_path}/ls-var-zfs-dsk.txt
fi
```

Amongst the resulting files, `ZFS file system properties.txt` lists properties for just **one** ZFS file system … a dataset with white space in its name.

The most desirable end result is properties:

- for all ZFS file systems
- in a file.

Removing the following string –

`&> ${data_directory_path}/ZFS\ file\ system\ properties.txt`

– does get properties for all ZFS file systems, in a window of Terminal but not in a file. That's enough for me to accept an answer.

---

The *output to file* criterion, which wasn't in my first edition of the question, may be easily answered elsewhere.

Comment: Chat, with reference to the second edition of this question: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7661588#7661588

Comment: Alongside the accepted answer below, with [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/62583/84988) (to [How can I take the output of a shell script and place it in a file on the command line?](http://superuser.com/q/62581/84988)) I realise that for the output to file – for the **append** – I need `>>` (not  `&>` or  `&>>`). In feedback to Apple I asked for `sysdiagnose` to be added to [Apple Open Source](http://www.opensource.apple.com) – if this happens I'll make public my other changes to the script, most of which are unrelated to ZFS.

Comment: Appreciating the age of the question and that it might have been simplified for brevity, what was wrong with simply `for DS in $(zfs list -H -o name); do zfs get all "$DS"; done`?  I've been using that idiom in my own scripts for a while and am hoping I haven't missed anything (note the use of `-o name` and `"`-quoting to limit the output (no longer needs `cut`) and handle spaces in dataset names (even though space is *supposed* to be an invalid char for dataset names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Not splitting at spaces

bash's `for` loop splits the argument at all whitespace characters by default. You could somehow escape each line - or simply switch to another delimiter character. `cut` will return one value per line, so there's a newline in between which we can choose.

Watch out for the double quotes in `zfs get all`, so each `$dataset` doesn't get split up, too.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for dataset in `zfs list -H | cut -f 1`
do
  zfs get all "$dataset"
done
```

## Resetting IFS

Afterwards, you might want to reset `IFS` to the value before, store it to some temporary variable.

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
# the whitespaces-sensitive lines
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Comment: [This (paste)](http://pastebin.com/uYZZvJtn) results in [properties for only one dataset](http://pastebin.com/Ws2BphP8). [An alternative approach](http://pastebin.com/xNdzTKHC) [fails in a different way](http://pastebin.com/FKzecnfx). http://pastebin.com/nJQZq64s shows datasets at the time of writing. Should I edit the original question to include more detail?

Comment: Aye, using `/bin/sh` does work for me on OS X (links to `bash` here), but I'm experiencing same problems on ubuntu linux (linking `sh` to `dash`). Try changing the shebang (see updated answer), `dash` doesn't seem to interprete the `\n` as newline but 'n' character instead. PS: +1 for own effort in solving problem and adding a link to the `zfs list` output to the question wouldn't hurt anyone but offer some reference. By the way, looks your tabs got replaced by spaces while uploading, had to undo that before `cut` working properly.

Comment: `/bin/bash` did not workaround. I edited the question to include more context, and to show more clearly how I'm experimenting based on this answer. Partial success. I could be making some very basic mistake somewhere! Thanks …

Comment: Oh, you have another problem, that's not the one I had - didn't realize this while digging to your pastes for the first time... Using `printf` was unnecessarily complicated anyway, just wrap it in double quotes: `zfs get all "$dataset"`. I guess it should run fine now.